# Decode nested array from dictionary Swift

Tags: json, swift, utf-8

I'm getting this error: `"Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."`, while trying to decode Dictionary JSON?

JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "totalResults": 69,
  "results": []
}
```

How can i skip status and totalResults and decode only results?

My code:

```
struct News: Decodable {
  var title: String
  var content: String
}

let jsonUrl = URL(string: "https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=pub_297524faa4f21de311b826df181186f8e33b&q=travelling&language=en")

var news = [News]()

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonUrl!) { data, response, error in
    do {
        news = try JSONDecoder().decode([News].self, from: data!)
        news.forEach { print($0.title) }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}.resume()
```

PS asking here because 99% youtube tutorials explain only how to decode an array

Comment: `.decode([News].self, from: data!)`: Why did you write `[New].self` and not `New.self`? I know the meaning of both, but I'm asking you why (to make you understand).

Comment: it's my first try, and all of this done by me watching youtube tutorials :) I'm still not fully understand what's going on

Comment: try JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from: data!) try this. you are getting the response as JSON Object not as Array. so it shouldn't be [News]

Comment: _"How can i skip status and totalResults and decode only results?"_, you can omit those fields if you want to but you still need to decode from the top so you need a struct that holds the `result` array and use that when decoding.

Answer (score -1):

to decode your json data you must first get the correct swift data model that match the data.
A quick way to do this, is to copy and paste your json data into "https://quicktype.io/".
This site will give you the swift structs you need. Then you need to make a request call
to the server. Here is the code that does this, given the swift data structs.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var results = [Result]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(results) { news in
                VStack {
                    Text(news.title)
                    Text(news.link).foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            loadNews()
        }
    }
    
    func loadNews() {
        let jsonUrl = URL(string: "https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=YOURAPIKEY&q=travelling&language=en")
        guard let url = jsonUrl else { return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                results = response.results
            }
            catch {
                print("---> error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let results: [Result]
    let nextPage: Int
}

struct Result: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let link: String
    let keywords: [String]?
    let creator: [String]?
    let videoURL: JSONNull?
    let resultDescription, content: String?
    let pubDate: String
    let fullDescription: String?
    let imageURL: String?
    let sourceID: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title, link, keywords, creator
        case videoURL = "video_url"
        case resultDescription = "description"
        case content, pubDate
        case fullDescription = "full_description"
        case imageURL = "image_url"
        case sourceID = "source_id"
    }
}

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

PS: do not post your secret API key. Remove it from your question, now.

EDIT-1:

if you really need for some reason, not to decode `status` and `totalResults` make the properties `let` and give them an initial value, as shown below. Xcode will tell you these will not be decoded.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let results: [Result]
    let status: String = ""   // <-- here give the let a value
    let totalResults: Int = 0 // <-- here give the let a value
    let nextPage: Int = 0     // <-- here give the let a value
}
```

or remove those fields if you never want to use them:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let results: [Result]
}
```